# How do I get the id's of children of siblings using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using this code and it outputs the correct objects, but I am unable to get only the id from these objects. Here is the code:

```
console.log($(this).parent().parent().siblings().children());
```

Output is:

[div#first-example.box-prop.top-widget, div#second-example.box-prop.top-widget, div#third-example.box-prop.top-widget, prevObject: init[3], context: i.fa.fa-times.close-x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var ids = $(this).parent().parent().siblings().children().map(function(e){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```